# Nonbinary file in Python

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I'm trying to look at all the items we have in a directory, and check whether there are file or directory. Sadly, all of them aren't directory, neither a file.

```
import io, sys, os, json
path_input = "C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\somewhere\\"
for file in os.listdir(path_input):
    
    print("Looking at " + file)
    isFile = os.path.isfile(file) # False
    isDir = os.path.isdir(file) # False
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something with how I handle file.

Comment: what is your working directory? You are only passing the filename/directory name...You need to pass either the full path or a valid relative path from your working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the path in my function to properly locate the file (or the directory)

```
    isDirectory = os.path.isdir(path_input+file)
```

Someone posted the solution but the post got deleted